# Rails 3 - How to use autocomplete with a few db fields as sources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, field, jquery-autocomplete

**Hey guys!**

## Details

I'm using the **rails3-jquery-autocomplete** gem (https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) for my search feature.

To realize the search, I'm using **meta-search** gem.

## Problem

My request is to realize a search on a radio model which contains few columns. Meta-search is able to do that but autocomplete gem seems to be currently limited to autocomplete from only one field at a time. I would like that the autocomplete will take as sources every field of the radio model.

Moreover, there are a few foreign keys in the radio model and I would like to get their corresponding values.

## Questions

Did you have such a problem or do you know how to face with it?

I looked around over all the questions in stackoveflow, and tried to use the commits of that guy who implemented himself that feature -> [Issue #15 on the gem github page](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/pull/15)

I would need maybe another gem or way to implement this autocomplete, so if you have any idea, don't hesitate to let me know.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I used the fork of some guy who implemented interesting stuff. But that wasn't working properly so I forked his fork and I modified to be able to use it.

If you need help to autocomplete from few fields and tables on rails 3, ruby 1.8.7 then you can give a try to my fork of the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem => https://github.com/dbachet/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

There is no support for mongoid, and options were not tested.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, how to do things like that.
One of them is to get some js autocomplete script, that can use external xml/json data source.
I like (and use) this one - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/AutoSuggestControl.aspx

Using it, what you need to do is to implement some action for some controller, that will query all data sources you want with "LIKE"-style query (getting all words that start with or contain a parameter given) and return it all in way like this:

```
format.xml  { response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
              render :inline => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'+
                                "<listdata>#{@tags.join('|')}</listdata>" };
```

@tags here is an array of all keywords you got with your query (or series of queries).

Your template will have a code like this:

```
<script>
  var obj = new autosuggest("someid", "", "http://mysite.org/tags.xml?term=");
</script>
```

Where "someid" is an "id" attribute of your search input, "/suggest.xml" is a path to your controller/action and "term" is your parameter for that action.
I hope this could help you.

Comment: I'd like to find the way to use the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem, later I could try another solution. Thx for help